# wrong Reading with BufferedReader

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader

I have problem with reading data from file.
In each line (except first) first char is lost!

Maybe i have troubles with coding, but i try to set UTF-8, UniCode, ANSI, and result is fast the same...

Code:

```
    try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("123.txt")) {
        // create a buffer for file reader
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        do {
            input = br.readLine();

            System.out.println(input);
        } while (br.read() != -1);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("IOex : " + ex);
    }
```

Console:

2
FFFFFF

FAF9F5

FDBCA1

FBCCB8

but must be:

2
#FFFFFF
2
#FAF9F5
6
#FDBCA1
9
#FBCCB8
9

it only works, when i put slashes before lines.

2
\#FFFFFF
\2
\#FAF9F5
\6
\#FDBCA1
\9
\#FBCCB8
\9

What can it be?
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you checking for `input` ending in `\n`? It can't, because you're using `readLine`! Please show the contents of the file.

Comment: i thinked, troblem was there. So is right)

Comment: You are reading a byte at the end of the loop and throwing it away.  You realise that `read()` actually does read a byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the end of your `do` loop:

```
do {
    input = br.readLine();
    if (input.endsWith("\n")) {
        input = input.substring(0, input.indexOf("\n"));
    }
    System.out.println(input);
} while (br.read() != -1);
```

You're calling `read()` which will read the first character of the next line - but you're *only* using that to check for whether the file has ended. (Notice how you've got the first character of the *first* line, because there you're calling `readLine` without previously calling `read`.)

This would work fine - and be simpler:

```
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

`readLine` returns `null` when you've reached the end of the data. Note that you don't need to check for `input` containing `\n` as you're already reading one line at a time, and `\n` is deemed to be a line separator.

Comment: +1 Suggest a for loop: `for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {` to limit the scope.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Yes, you've suggested that before - personally I prefer the `while` loop approach... the combined assignment and test is "nasty" enough, without being in a `for` loop with an empty `ForUpdate` part. The scope leakage is annoying, but not too bad IMO. Matter of personal preference, I guess.